# Editing a SPECIFIC word in a file in python, every 20 mins

Tags: python

I want to change the value of omega in the file below at a specific interval, say every 30 minutes. This file is used by another program at runtime. I would like to ramp the RPM value (the last entry on the line) from 0-10 slowly. Essentially, the value "5" in the file below needs to change from 0-10 in increments of 1 every 30 minutes.

```
rotor
{
    // Fixed patches (by default they 'move' with the MRF zone)
    nonRotatingPatches (); //if something blows up ..fill the non rotating patches between "(baffles, pressureOutlet etc)"

    origin    origin [0 1 0 0 0 0 0]  (0 0 0);
    axis      axis   [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]  (0 0 1);
    omega    omega [0 0 -1 0 0 0 0] 5;
}
```

I have tried the following code (I don't know how to do the every 30 minutes part), but the data written by the`file.writelines(data)` method doesn't seem to incorporate the change I make to the value.

```
import os
import sys
import fileinput

with open('MRFzones', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

# The line omega is line 27 in the file.
line = data[26]
word = line.split()

# >>> data[26].split()
# ['omega', 'omega', '[0', '0', '-1', '0', '0', '0', '0]', '5;'] 
# The part i want to change is the 10th word.
word[9] = '10;'

# Write everything back.
with open('MRFzones', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(data)
```

This is not working - the 5 is not being changed into 10 in the updated file. Can someone help me implement this? I might not even have the right idea, so we could start the code from scratch if necessary.

Thanks, 
Suresh

Answer (score 2):

You are not modifying `data` at all -- you are extracting `line` and `word` and modify those.  In the end, you write back the original `data` to the file.

I would not use Python for this, but rather a shell script (provided you are on a Unix-like OS):

```
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do
   sleep 30
   sed -i "26s/[0-9]+;/$i/" MRFzones
od
```

Comment: thanks for the response..i was learning python and was trying to do some automation using the program! Yes i use a similar script in unix to do the same. yours is much simpler though..what should python be used for in general!? -suresh

Comment: @user: I see, my answer is not very useful if your aim is learning Python rather than getting a job done :)

Comment: like i said.. the job is being done, but i was also wondering if i had to use python, how would i go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can identify your lines and its components via the `fileinput` module you imported, and the `re` module for regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r'(\s*omega\s+omega\s+\[-?\d+ -?\d+ -?\d+ -?\d+ -?\d+ -?\d+ -?\d+\]) (-?\d+);'
```

Enclosing braces are used to capture patterns, have a look at the [re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html?highlight=re) to know more (very useful Python module, very well done and documented) !

We have our pattern, now browse our file inplace: `print` is used to write in the file directly (no longer prints to screen), standard function comes back to normal when the `for` loop is over (file closed).

Don't forget to remove newlines to avoid having unrequired newlines in your output file (yes this is a bit annoying: the `line` variable given by the loop contains a newline `\n`) !

```
>>> from fileinput import FileInput
>>> path = 'D:\\Temp\\Toto.txt'
>>> for line in FileInput(path, inplace=1):
        line = line.replace('\n', '')
        match = re.match(pattern, line)
        if match:
            line = '{0} {1};'.format(match.groups()[0], '145')
            print line
        else:
            print line
```

You can now browse your old file, the value `5` was replaced by `145`.
I personally don't agree with Sven, Python is for me the perfect language to deal with this kind of situation.

Comment: +1 for `inplace=1`.  The code could be improved, though (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way of doing what you want is indeed to use the regular expression module ([re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-contents)).  It can perform the replacement  in the "omega" line directly:

```
import re

for count in range(10):

    # Reading:
    with open('MRFzones') as input_file:  # Automatically closes the file after reading
        contents = input_file.read()  # Whole file

    # Writing:
    with open('MRFzones', 'w') as out_file:
        # The 'omega.*(\d+)' searches for a line with "omega" followed at some point by digits and ";".  sub() performs
        # a substitution of the part matched inside the parentheses:
        out_file.write(re.sub('omega +(\d+);', str(count), contents, count=1))  # count=1 only modifies the first omega line
```

Comment: There must be '?' after '.*' in ``'omega.*(\d+);'`` , otherwise ``(\d+)`` will match only the last digit of the last number, that is to say '1' when the number will be '10'. By the way, I don't see why it should be ``'.*?'`` instead of ``' +'`` , since there is nothing else than blanks before the desired number

Comment: @eyquem: Thanks.  I think I initially meant ` *` (instead of `.*`).

Answer (score 1):

With Python, you could use a regex and processing in a file with mode 'rb+':

```
import re
from time import sleep

regx = re.compile('^ +omega +omega +\[[ \d.eE+-]+\] +(\d\d?)(;.+)',re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

for i in xrange(1,11):
    sleep(20*60)
    with open('MRFzones', 'rb+') as f:
        m = regx.search(f.read())
        x = m.start(1)
        f.seek(x,0)
        f.writelines((str(i),m.group(2)))
        f.tuncate()
```

I suppose that the initial file is containing

```
'     omega    omega [0 0 -1 0 0 0 0] 0;'
```

**m** is the MatchObject that records the results of the matching
Among these results, there are:

- the position in the file's content where starts the 1 or 2 digit(s) sequence that is catched by the first group in the match, the one defined by `(\d\d?)` . This start is obtained via method **start()** of **m** called with 1 as argument
- the text catched by second group in the match, defined by `(;.+)`, obtained by method **group()** of **m** called with 2 as argument

**re.MULTILINE** makes the symbol **'^'** in the pattern of the regex to match with each start of line, that is precisely after each `'\n'` and at the beginning of the string. Without **re.MULTILINE** , **'^'** means only the matching with the beginning of the string

**re.DOTALL** makes the dot in the pattern to match with any character, comprised the newlines. So `';.+'` means : the character **';'** and all and every characters that follow **';'** until the very end of the string. Without **re.DOTALL**, the symbolic dot in the pattern would stop to match at the end of the line.

After the execution of  `f.read()` , the file's pointer is situated at the end of the file on the hard drive. **seek()** allows to move it. In this case, `seek(x,0)` moves the pointer to a position that is situated at **x** characters from the start of the file (the 0 means 'from the start', see seek() to learn the other types of moves)

After the execution of `f.seek(x,0)` , the pointer is just before the integer you want to change. Writing **str(i)** erases and writes on the ancient number.

`f.truncate()` is to make the file ending at the current position. In the case of my code, it's not absolutely necesssary , since the string that is replaced is always replaced by a string of same or longer length.

.

Note that this code can be simplified if there are two positions reserved for the number in the file where can be written two characters: ' 0', ' 1', ' 2', ' 3',  etc

In this case the code can be:

```
import re
from time import sleep

regx = re.compile('^ +omega +omega +\[[ \d.eE+-]+\] +(\d\d?)',re.MULTILINE)

for i in xrange(1,11):
    sleep(20*60)
    with open('MRFzones', 'rb+') as f:
        m = regx.search(f.read())
        x = m.start(1)
        f.seek(x,0)
        f.write('{:>2}'.format(i))
```

or

```
import re
from time import sleep

regx = re.compile('^ +omega +omega +\[[ \d.eE+-]+\] +(\d\d?)(;.+)',re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

with open('Copie de oso.txt', 'rb+') as f:
    m = regx.search(f.read())
    x = m.start(1)
    f.seek(x,0)
    f.writelines((' 1',m.group(2)))
    f.truncate()

for i in xrange(2,11):
    sleep(20)
    with open('Copie de oso.txt', 'rb+') as f:
        f.seek(x,0)
        f.write('{:>2}'.format(i))
```

.

**PS**

Brackets **'['** and **']'** of the symbolic sequence `[ \d.eE+-]` in the pattern define a set of characters. I put between these two brackets all the characters that are likely to be used to write a number. It is important that **'-'** be at the end of the set, otherwise it would mean anaother thing that just the **'-'** character.

`'\['` and `'\]'` are the escaped brackets, to represent just the characters 'brackets', not  the symbolic brackets that define a set

I choosed to catch **'[0 0 -1 0 0 0 0]'** with the part `\[[ \d.eE+-]+\]` of the pattern in case that the numbers could be any other kind of number, expressed in any sort of representation (comprised exponential notation)

`' +'` in the pattern means 'any number of blanks'